# php artisan migrate: with mamp: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: php, laravel, mamp

I have a Laravel project with MAMP. I tried to connect to my database with MySQL Server in phpMyAdmin. The `php artisan migrate` command gives this error:

```
  Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select max(`batch`) as aggregate from `migrations`)

  at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/todoapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668| 

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/todoapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=tododb", "root", "root", [])
      /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/todoapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

my env. file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=tododb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Comment: Check your MySQL password for user root

Comment: Your database credentials are incorrect, check the db port of your mamp installation

Answer (score 1):

Please check your database connection credentials. It looks like your user "root" doesn't have access to it. If your user credentials is right, check the MySQL config file, looking for authentication method allowed.

Comment: thanks , i found the answer by myself , just wrong port number

Comment: But, have you changed the port number on your MySQL service? Because the default port is right on your example